# Lookup Function returning invalid integer value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I am currently working on a spreadsheet to compare stock values and am trying to find mistakes using Lookup or VLookup.

[image]

For some reason, this returns "8" causing the if statement to output false.

```
=IF(LOOKUP(L12,$L$8:$L11,$Q$8:Q$13)=Q12,FALSE,"MISTAKE")
```

It is saying "$Q$8:Q$13 = 8" and I have no idea why this could be. I have spent the last 2 days working on this and looking up solutions to this online as well as reading the doc. I can't, however, seem to solve this.

Comment: Shouldn't the second (`$L$8:$L11`) and the third (`$Q$8:Q$13`) arguments be the same size? Could you describe the logic of what you want to achieve with you formula?

Comment: Hello krishkin. I want to check if the item in the first column you see here exists again. Then I want to compare the value of that row with the value of the row we are checking. Thank you! :)

Comment: And if the value is the same as we've seen the first time, then it's ok, right?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing everything from the column `Z` and putting this in `Z1`:

```
={
  "Whatever Header you have there in column Z";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
      IFNA(VLOOKUP(L2:L, {L$2:L, Q$2:Q}, 2, 0)) = Q2:Q,
        FALSE,
        "MISTAKE"
    )
  )
}
```

With `ARRAYFORMULA` put in the top row like that you will not have to copy and paste your formula every time you insert a new row.

But if you just need your formula to be fixed and if I understand you correctly then your formula in `Z12` should be (one of the ways):

```
=IF(
  IFNA(VLOOKUP(L12, {L$8:L11, Q$8:Q11}, 2, 0), Q12) = Q12,
    FALSE,
    "MISTAKE"
)
```